# Flutter Gallery demo: Cards to change card's height

Tags: flutter

I am trying to modify the `cards_demo.dart` found in Flutter examples. My purpose is that instead of having the built-in two cards' height be fixed as:

`static final double height=300.0` (or some mandatory and fixed number), I want to have different height for the two cards.

So I modified the `TravelDestination` class to include a property `height`:

```
class TravelDestination {
  const TravelDestination({ this.assetName, this.title, this.description, this.height });

  final String assetName;
  final String title;
  final List<String> description;
  final double height;

  bool get isValid => assetName != null && title != null && description?.length == 3;
}
```

Then, in class `TravelDestinationItem` `build` function:

```
class TravelDestinationItem extends StatelessWidget {
  TravelDestinationItem({ Key key, @required this.destination }) : super(key: key) {
    assert(destination != null && destination.isValid);
  }

  static final double height = 512.0;
  final TravelDestination destination;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final TextStyle titleStyle = theme.textTheme.headline.copyWith(color: Colors.white);
    final TextStyle descriptionStyle = theme.textTheme.subhead;

    return new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      height: destination.height,
      //height: height,
      child: new Card(
        child: new Column(... ...
```

I assigned different `height` property to the two cards but the result is not working: they are still the same height as specified by `static final double height`.

If I comment out `static final double height` line, the compiler will remind me: `No static getter 'height' declared...`

I am very much confused on this behavior.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using items of varying height, you should remove this line from the call to the `ListView` constructor:

```
itemExtent: TravelDestinationItem.height,
```

Also, you'll need to hot-restart the app (hot-reloading won't update the destinations list with the new data, since it's a global variable).

Comment: Thanks! Noticed this later.